# Manga with a pink-haired witch who is the daughter of a noble family in a historical setting

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magic, manga, isekai

I'm trying to find a manga that I once read. The main character is a female lead (FL) with pink hair. She is also a witch in a kingdom/empire (I don't remember which one it was) where witches were hunted. The FL is the last/one of the last witches and gets taken away by the emperor to remove/solve a curse from another witch.

It is probably an isekai (reincarnation)/time travel, because she remembers (from a book or past life, I don't know) that she died at the palace (I forgot how). I believe that the FL was able to transform into a bird. She also has a caring family and they tried to hide her when the emperor came (when the emperor was at their mansion, the FL transformed herself into a bird and at some point, the emperor put her in a birdcage).

I believe that, at the capital, she lived alone (without other nobles, but with maids and so on) in a mansion.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Isekai is portal fantasy where someone is transported to another world. Do you think that was the case, or just reincarnation or time travel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is ***[The Tyrant's Tranquilizer](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5uzxfpv/the-tyrant-s-tranquilizer)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Amelie Bourbon is a witch, destined to die at the hands of her lover, the ruthless tyrant Serwin Hennessia. So when ordinary office worker Lee Suyeon is reborn as Amelie, she vows to change the ill-fated story. The problem is the “calamity” sealed inside Serwin’s body, which threatens to ruin him and the entire world, can only be calmed when he is near Amelie. As she grows closer to Serwin, Amelie must hone her magic to subdue his violent impulses, but can she defeat calamity once and for all?

The protagonist, Lee Soo-Yeon, was an office worker who'd been reading a fantasy novel about a noblewoman, Renee Delaheim, who kills a tyrannical emperor to avenge her sister, Amelie Bourbon, who'd been imprisoned and executed by the emperor.

Upon reading the final chapter of the novel, however, Soo-Yeon is frustrated by the unhappy ending, and goes to sleep thinking that she could've written a better ending than the author. She then wakes up inside the world of the novel as Amelie.

Amelie is a pink-haired witch who, at this point in the story, is alive and well, and has been living away from her father, Count Delaheim, and sister, Renee, for some time. She goes to pay them a visit for the first time in years, but her visit coincides with a visit from the emperor.

Wishing to avoid an encounter with the emperor, Amelie transforms into a bird and attempts to hide in the corner of the room, next to a plant pot. The emperor spots her from across the room, however, grabs her, and subsequently places her into a bird cage.

[image] [image]

Comment: ^_^ Your answer is much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Not reincarnation as far as I can tell, but maybe [*Izetta: The Last Witch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izetta:_The_Last_Witch)?

> Set in an alternate Earth on the eve of the Second World War, the story follows Izetta, the last surviving member of a clan of witches that possesses the ability to magically manipulate any object that they touch. Izetta pledges to help protect Princess Finé and the tiny Alpine country of Eylstadt from invasion by the imperialistic forces of Germania

One of the reasons she is recruited is because the opposing emperor has his own witch (later revealed to be a clone created by his weapons division) who is empowering Germanic weapons.

### Opening